# How to view google cloud build results grouped by repository

Tags: google-cloud-build

In Google Cloud Build history, there is by default a list of build which have been run recently. With this view, the status of the different builds are not visible.

How to get some "Jenkins-like" view, where I can see all builds grouped by repositories with their last run (or last few runs) and status? Is there such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can thanks to the filter field. However, it's not really userfriendly. Enter this in the filter field `source.repo_source.repo_name= "github_guillaumeblaquiere_bqtoftp"` for filter all repo source displayed like this in the GUI: `GitHub guillaumeblaquiere/bqToFtp`.

It's not very intuitive, but that works!

Then, you can compose your query as you want, with AND/OR parenthesis, = or !=. Thereby, you will be able to easily filter your status. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results#filtering_build_results_using_queries) an example

Last word. When your filter works on the GUI, it's the same in command line. If you need to script something, it could help!

Comment: If I understand that correctly, this works for one repository. However, the goal of this question is to get a quick overwiew which builds are currently healthy and which not.

Comment: You want a view of the lastest (1 to 5) build on each repository, for having a kind of dashboard ?

Comment: Well, a simple solution would be to have a list of repositories with one build status (the most recent). Ideally, there it should also be possible to see different branches, or if possible 1-5 most recent builds for each repo and branch. Depending on what is possible, but something similar to a dashboard

Comment: Ok, I worked some years ago and I see what do you want. However, this is not possible with Cloud Build. A solution can be to export Cloud Build and sink them to BiqQuery, and then to build a Datastudio dashboard on top of the BigQuery table. But, I just had a look to log structure, and it's quite hard to understand when the build is OK or failed, and you even don't have the Repository name! Userfriendly...